# Copy gridview rows in another gridview on a button_click

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, copy

I have a textBox and a search button that fills the first Gridview. After that a Second Button Copies the first grid rows in the second grid . After that i should be able to search again in the first grid and attach the other results to the second grid.
But i get an error. Thnx in advance.
Here is my code:

```
public partial class Grid: System.Web.UI.Page
```

{

```
DataTable Dt = new DataTable();
private DataTable Dt1
{
    set { ViewState.Add("Dt1", value); }
    get { return (DataTable)ViewState["Dt1"]; }
}


private void Fill_grid()
{
    string query = "Select * from table " +
    " where field1 like '" + TextBox1.Text + "' or filed2 like '" +TextBox1.Text + "'";       

    SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(...);
    SqlCommand cmm = new SqlCommand(query,cnn);
    cmm.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
    SqlDataAdapter MyDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmm);
    DataSet DS = new DataSet();
    cnn.Open();
    MyDataAdapter.Fill(DS, "Client");
    Dt1 = DS.Tables["klient"];
    DataView dv = new DataView(Dt1);
    GridView2.DataSource = DS.Tables["klient"].DefaultView;
    GridView2.DataBind();


}
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Fill_grid();
}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Fill_Second_Grid();
}

private void Fill_Second_Grid()
{

    DataRow dr;

    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView2.Rows)
    {
        dr = Dt.NewRow();
            dr["Email"] = row.Cells[0].Text; ;
            Dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    }

    GridView3.DataSource = Dt;
    GridView3.DataBind();
}
```

}

Comment: It'd help to know what error you are getting... edit your question to include this information.

Comment: the field name is "filed2" or "field2"?